# Express Sentences Using Mathematical symbols

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I know this supposed to be relatively simple but I'm not sure if I am doing the questions right.  I am relatively new to logic and abstract math.  I have [attached the questions and my attempts at a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2xNL.jpg).  Any help would be much welcomed.

> Suppose that $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval and that $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function.  Write the following two sentences using mathematical symbols:
>
> 1. The function is not a constant function.
> 2. The function does not take the same value twice.

My attempt:

1. $\forall B\in\mathbb{R},\exists x\in A, f(x)\ne B$.
2. $\forall x\in A, f(x_1)=f(x_2) \rightarrow x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: I strongly recommend you try to learn how to use MathJax, that is the way to codify math using Latex in SE (StackExchange) to express your ideas in writing using appropriate math symbols.Easier to read.

Comment: Can you please check that my transcription of your answers is correct?  If so, (1) gets you there, though it might be better to say $\exists x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$ (that is, there exist two values in $A$ that give different outputs).  For (2), what are $x_1$ and $x_2$?  and where do you ever use $x$?  Maybe you meant $\forall x_1,x_2\in A$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: My immediate instinct for (1) matches yours, but it's not actually clear to me that it's "better". If we push the negation outwards in the OP's solution we get $\neg(\exists B\in\mathbb R)(\forall x\in A)f(x)=B$, which seems to say extremely directly that $f$ is not constant.

Comment: Hello, Yeah that is a correct transcription.  For 2,  I wasn't really sure what I was doing, that was all I could think of.

Comment: Any help for 2, would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I agree entirely, hence my prevarication leading up to the suggested change.  That said, I think that your phrasing is the most clear.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for question 2.

Comment: notation for it's strictly increasing/decreasing  you mean ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure how to express using notation that the function doesn't take same value twice. i think my attempt is incorrect

Comment: To say the function does take the same value twice, I'd say $\exists x_1, x_2 \in A, x_1 \ne x_2 \wedge f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Now, what do you get if you negate that?

Comment: Is this the negation:  for every x1 and x2 that are elements of A, x1 does not equal x2 implies f(x1) does not equal f(x2)??

Comment: I don't know how to type symbols in stackexchange, so the above comment is my negation in words.  Is this correct?

Comment: $\land$ is the logical "and", not an implication.

Comment: so would the negation include disjunction

Comment: @kemb  you use [MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#alphaList)  a similar language to TeX eg. :  `$\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty i$` produces $\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty i$

Comment: yeah I don't know TeX, although I should probably learn.

Comment: where as `$$\sum_\limits{i-1}^\infty i$$` produces it on a new line $$\sum_\limits{i-1}^\infty i$$

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, (1) looks fine, though I really like HenningMakholm's slightly modified

> $\neg(\exists B\in\mathbb{R})(\forall x\in A)f(x)=B$.

For (2), the conclusion is correct, i.e. $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \to x_1 = x_2$.  However, you did not ever tell us where $x_1$ and $x_2$ live.  Since we want this statement to hold true for all $x_1$ and $x_2$, let's say so!  Hence I might propose the solution

> $(\forall x_1,x_2\in A) (f(x_1)=f(x_2)\to x_1=x_2)$.

Alternatively, we could use the idea that if we fix $x_1$ first, then go searching for an $x_2$, we are never going to find one that gives the same value when evaluating $f$.  Perhaps something like

> $(\forall x_1\in A)\neg(\exists x_2\in A)(x_1 \ne x_2 \land f(x_1)=f(x_2))$.

If I have correctly formatted things (these notation-heavy, "English free" sentences always give me a headache), we should be able to read this as "For every $x_1\in A$, there does not exist an $x_2\in A$ such that both $x_1\ne x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$."  That is, given any $x_1$, we cannot produce an $x_2$ different from $x_1$ that gives a different value of $f$.  If we are happy working with set operations, we might also write

> $(\forall x_1\in A)\neg(\exists x_2\in A\setminus\{x_1\})f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Comment: Thanks!.  I am just not sure how the second answer for (2) shows that a function doesn't take the same value twice.  I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the correction.  If I put the first answer for (2) would that also be considered a correct solution?

Comment: Indeed, that should get the job done.

Comment: The set explanation makes much more sense to me.  Thank you.